# How to have live snippets in vscode like latex suite in obsidian

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, obsidian

I love using the latex suite extension in obsidian, where it would auto replace texts like mk into latex equation symbols $$, and aa into \alpha , and much more. I want to know if there is an vscode extension that can do this.

I tried installing the latex utility extension, and for an hour it was working: it could replace mk with $$ and i could press tab for tab stops. But somehow it is not working now, despite enabling live snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LaTeX Utilities extension. It has been updated. By default it doesn't have snippet for math mode $$. But you can create your own by editing snippet in settings.json file.
Ex:

```
{
      "prefix": "mk$",
      "body": " \\($$1\\) ",
      "mode": "text",
      "description": "inline math mode",
      "triggerWhenComplete": true
    },
```